# Film about a dying Earth, so a crew of astronauts are sent to save human race in a distant planet

Tags: story-identification, movie, spaceship, artificial-intelligence

Film *might* be base on a novel from Stephen Baxter: [*Ark*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ark_%28Baxter_novel%29) (2009)

- extreme climate (flood, huricane..) has made life impossible on Earth
- astronauts are sent to another star so they can save the human race
- spaceship is controlled by a computer like HAL 9000
- yes, it kills their captain
- ... by taking out the air in the pressure chamber
- close to Saturn (I think) they must decide go/no-go
- their interstellar spacecraft is propelled by nuclear explosions
- think it's a 2000-2010

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image: Virtuality (2009) - Cast Pic]

[**Virtuality** (2009)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1219836/)

> A spaceship from Earth is equipped with a virtual-reality device to
>   help those aboard cope with their 10-year mission. But when the system
>   malfunctions, it puts the Phaeton's crew -- and the fate of their
>   planet -- in jeopardy.

From the movie's [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtuality_%28TV_pilot%29) page, here are a few plot points:

> The pilot picks up approximately six months after the launch of the
>   Phaeton [and it's getting closer and closer to Neptune]. *The crew now
>   faces a "go or no-go" situation*, in that they are fast approaching
>   their last chance to change course back towards Earth.
>
> However, *their home planet is quickly becoming uninhabitable, with dry land becoming a commodity*. Scientists estimate that the planet
>   will become completely inhospitable within the next hundred years. The
>   Phaeton's priority mission has been changed to that of searching out
>   and *discovering a new planet for humans to inhabit.*

[image: Virtuality (2009) - Pic 01]

The AI begins to take control of the ship...

> *[Lately] the crew's virtual reality simulators have been experiencing several bizarre glitches*, all of which involve a mysterious man,
>   whose acts against the crew inside the virtual simulations become more
>   and more disturbing.

[image: Virtuality (2009) - Pic 02]

Commander Frank Pike is the one leading the mission. A description of the "accident":

> The communications array fails to deploy, and after Dr. Jules Braun
>   tries everything that he can from inside the ship, Pike, Rika, Val
>   Orlovsky and Manny Rodriguez prepare to identify the problem from the
>   outside.
>
> While preparing for EVA [Extra-vehicular activity], *the airlock
>   chamber closes by itself, with Pike inside* and without his pressure
>   suit helmet. Despite efforts to save him, *the airlock opens and Pike
>   is killed.*

<sup>*~ Synopsis from [allmovie](https://www.allmovie.com/movie/virtuality-v492705); Images from [DEN OF GEEK!](https://www.denofgeek.com/tv/9332/virtuality-pilot-review), [NY Daily News](https://web.archive.org/web/20190120182558/https://www.nydailynews.com/entertainment/tv-movies/fox-sci-fi-reality-movie-virtuality-delivers-real-boredom-battlestar-galactica-ties-article-1.375465) and [TrekMovie.com](https://trekmovie.com/2009/06/26/briefing-for-ron-moores-virtuality-tv-movie-and-possible-series-pilot-airing-tonight/)*</sup>

Read more about it [here](https://www.wired.com/underwire/2009/06/ron-moores-tv-movie-virtuality-takes-vr-to-outer-space/) and [here](https://trekmovie.com/2009/06/26/briefing-for-ron-moores-virtuality-tv-movie-and-possible-series-pilot-airing-tonight/).